# What does error occurred while evaluating nil.dependencies mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm running ruby on rails v2.2.2 and when I run rake gems I get this error.

> $ rake gems --trace
>   - [I] settingslogic
>   rake aborted!
>   You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>   The error occured while evaluating nil.dependencies
>   /vendor/rails/railities/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:77:in `dependencies'

Comment: I've just tried it with Rails 2.2.2 and a new (empty) Rails project on Ruby 1.8.6 with RubyGems 1.3.1. It works fine for me. It would help to know what versions of these you are using. Do you get the same error when you run the task in a clean Rails project?

Comment: Also do you have any gems in the project? And what version of Rails did you use to create the project?

Comment: It would be useful if you could post your entire stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. There is a bug in the core rake gems function where it assumed there were specifications for the gem and would error out when it didn't exist for that gem.

Here is the ticket for this issue with a working patch
http://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/1464

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with a gem it's trying to load, or your setup of required gems. Check config/environment.rb for any odd-looking `config.gem` lines, and do an update of all your gems (sudo gem update).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit more detail [here](http://www.nabble.com/config.gem-dependencies-broken--td20770884.html) with two alternate workarounds
-add one line to the dependency code in rails
or 
-specify gem dependencies before the gem